# Component inside ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I'm using a form displayed inside a modal popup which is created using `ng-bootstrap`. Within the modal I'm using a custom component to display validation messages for each form field but it doesn't look like that component is being picked up and executed by the Angular lifecycle.

I open the popup from it's parent component using a button:

```
<button type="button" (click)="openFormModal()">Add something</button>
```

Which executes the following code where `MyModalComponent` has been imported:

```
openFormModal() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent);
}
```

The modal itself is fairly unremarkable apart from the custom `validation-messages` component. The code sample has various things omitted for brevity:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form">
    <input type="text" [ngClass]="'form-control'" formControlName="name" required maxlength="100">
    <validation-messages [control]="myForm.controls.names" controlName="Name"></validation-messages>
  </form>
</div>
```

The `validation-messages` component is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from './notifications.validation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'validation-messages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null" class="invalid-notification">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ValidationMessages {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor() { }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && (this.control.touched && this.control.invalid)) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.controlName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

`validation-messages` works perfectly in a standard form i.e. not in a modal but when the HTML for the modal renders on the screen the `validation-messages` renders as follows:

```
<validation-messages controlname="Name"></validation-messages>
```

Instead of how it renders normally:

```
<validation-messages controlname="Business name" ng-reflect-control="[object Object]" ng-reflect-control-name="Business name">
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
  }-->
</validation-messages>
```

I'm pretty new to Angular and I'm sure that it's something pretty fundamental that I'm missing.

It's probably also worth mentioning that I had to add `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],` to my `app.module.ts` to get the modal to not complain about the `validation-messages` component being present in the HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

`validation-messages` is also part of a notifications module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ValidationMessages } from "./notifications.validationmessages";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ValidationMessages],
    exports: [ValidationMessages]
  })
export class NotificationsModule {}
```

Comment: Rather than adding the `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`, have you tried adding the `ValidationMessages` component to `declarations` in your `app.module.ts` - i.e.  `declarations: [..., ValidationMessages]`

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the comment. I've edited the question slightly, because the component is declared in the module now included above it errors out if I also add it to the `app.module.ts` `declarations`.

Comment: Can you create a replica on stackblitz?

Comment: Does the `NotificationsModule` make it's way up to the imports of the global application module (`app.module.ts`) e.g. `imports: [..., NotificationsModule]`

Comment: It wasn't no but adding it in has fixed the issue. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it accepted. Does adding that make the component available at the root level? Many thanks!

Comment: Cheers, added an answer and also answered your question regarding if the component is available at the root level in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message regarding adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` gave a clue that Angular did not know about the `ValidationMessages` component. As your `ValidationMessages` component is part of the `NotificationsModule` you need to ensure that this module finds it way up into the global application module (often `app.module.ts`).

Modifying `app.module.ts` as follows should fix the issue:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        NotificationsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Regarding the comment "*Does adding that make the component available at the root level?*" - it will only be available at the root level if you add it to the `exports` of the `NotificationsModule` - like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ValidationMessages } from "./notifications.validationmessages";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ValidationMessages],
    exports: [ValidationMessages] // Available at root level/other modules
  })
export class NotificationsModule {}
```